# inDesign extract special objects form plain text paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

i'm trying to find a way to get only the plain text contained in a paragraph, and exclude the special objects contained in the para.

This is an example of my case.

I have this paragraph, obtained with app.activeDocument. :
[paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Juv1.png) , which contains 2 graphics before the plain text.

I achived this by doing:

```
var style  = app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item("My Para Style");
app.findTextPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = style;
var list = app.activeDocument.findText();
```

If I print the paragraph contents by `list[0].paragraphs[0].contents`, this is what is written: [printed paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfgQu.png).

How can I extract and replace only the plain text from this paragraph leaving the first 2 objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try list[0].paragraphs[0].texts and loop through the array of texts to put it together